# How to disable foreign character insertion through hotkey in Windows?

Tags: windows-10

I am developing an app that relies on the key combo `Ctrl+Shift+Alt`. This is getting problematic for me, as the default behavior of `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+(Letter)` is to insert the foreign language equivalent of that letter. For example: `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+E` inserts `Ē`.

I want to disable this foreign language character insertion in Windows (Chrome/VS Code/any application). What do I do?

Comment: Disable that key combination with AutoHoyKey. See this link: https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks! I'm looking for a way to disable the key combo directly from Windows though; but your solution is certainly handy for AHK users!